# installing mpich2 always installs me mpich

Tags: linux, mpi, mpich

I have mpif90 for MPICH version 3.0.4, but I want to remove it and install mpich2. There is a problem with the dislin library, so I need mpich2.

While on my debian distro `sudo apt-get install mpich2` installs me **mpif90 for MPICH2 version 1.4.1** (it is the right one I need), if I run (on Ubuntu where I already have MPICH version 3.0.4) `sudo apt-get remove libmpich10 libmpich-dev` and then `sudo apt-get install mpich2` it still installs mpif90 for MPICH version 3.0.4

How can I do?

> UPDATE 1

Thanks. But if I try to install it with `dpkg -i mpich2_1.4.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` I first have to remove the previous version 3.0.4, because they are in conflict.

I remove it, I try to install the 1.4.1 but there are unsolved dependencies (**libmpich2-3** -1.4.1 NOT INSTALLABLE, libcr0 NOT INSTALLED, libhwloc4, hwloc-nox). So as suggested I run `apt-get -f install` but it installs 3.0.4
On Debian it works fine, 64 bit, wheezy release. On Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how you can downgrade vendor-packaged mpich-3.0.4 to mpich2-1.4.1

Debian and Ubuntu make upgrading really easy.  Downgrading is a little tricky and might require pinning a package, rebuilding an old .deb for a newer platform, or you can just build MPICH2-1.4.1 from source.

Debian: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mpich2

Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mpich2

Source: http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4.1/

A word of caution: if you ask anybody for help with MPICH2-1.4, the very first thing you are going to hear is "wow, that is 2 years old.  can you try the latest version?"